# Default Page template Override Custom page templatein wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have Created Custom page template for my blog page. I can select template from admin page edit section. but in front end it shows default page layout. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

Please select page from admin side as your home page :-

```
Dashboard => Settings => Front page dislay => Static page
```